# Question about stationary phase with Hessian close to $0$

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, oscillatory-integral

Let $\phi$ be a smooth real function in one variable and say $w$ is a smooth function with compact support say $[- 1, 1]$. Let me define
$$
I_{\lambda} = \int_{\mathbb{R}} w(t) e^{i \lambda \phi(t)} dt
$$
where $\lambda > 0$ is a parameter that goes to infinity.
If we know that the Hessian of $\phi$ is bounded away from $0$ on $[-1,1]$ then we can apply the well known stationary phase method if there is a critical point in $[-1,1]$, otherwise we get a rapid decay. The assumption that Hessian is away from $0$ seems crucial for the application of stationary phase and is present in every source  regarding stationary phase I have looked at so far.

For simplicity let us assume there is only one critical point on $[-1,1]$ for my question.
I was interested in learning what is out there regarding how to deal with the case when the Hessian may become $0$ at the critical point (or Hessian is non-zero on $[-1,1]$ but can become close to $0$ with respect to $\lambda$).

One example I am interested in  an asymptotic for $I_{\lambda}$ when
$\phi(t) = (t-1)^3$. here there is a determinant $0$ critical point at the boundary...

Any reference or input would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This follows the basic estimates for the Fresnel integral (see for example the wiki article about stationary phase), for example you could have asked this about a quadratic phase function and it will be exactly what described there. 

I think the complete (smoothed) version appears in Tao’s notes.

Comment: If $\phi(t) = t^2$ , then the Hessian is nonzero everywhere, so it would not be part of my question. Is this what you mean?

Comment: If your Hessian vanishes in the interior of $(-1,1)$, you can use higher order van der corput lemmas https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Corput_lemma_(harmonic_analysis) In your example where $\phi(t) = (t-1)^3$, then you actually have still rapid decay. This is because if $w(t)$ is a smooth function with compact support, then $w(t) / (t-1)^k$ is also a smooth function of compact support for any $k$.

Comment: Since you asked for a reference: Eli Stein's big orange book  _Harmonic Analysis: Real-variable Methods, Orthogonality and Oscillatory Integrals_ has a pretty complete discussion in Chapter 8; note that the single variable theory is rather more developed than the multivariable theory.

Comment: @WillieWong thank you for this!

Comment: @WillieWong is the method of stationary phase when the critical point is degenerate well understood say when the number of variables is 2 or 3 nowadays? or is this still a very complicated matter?

Comment: In concrete cases you can almost always do things by hand. The issue is that things depend on exactly how degenerate the degeneracy is. For example, for studying the wave equations you have critical points whose Hessian has a one dimensional kernel only, and in this case the theory is very robust. But when you have, say, a situation with a higher dimensional kernel and that in the direction of the kernel you have some lower bounds of the third derivatives, it takes a lot of book keeping to combine all relevant effects.

Comment: In concrete cases if you benefit from it you can do it by hand. But keeping track of all the different possibilities makes it a nightmare to try to write down a "general theorem".

Comment: @WillieWong Very helpful! Thank you again!!